# Lipschitz and Uniqueness of an IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, lipschitz-functions

> Consider the IVP $$\frac{dx}{dt}=1+x^2, \ \ \ x(0)=1.$$ I am trying to show that $f(x)=1+x^2$ is Lipschitz and hence the above IVP has a unique solution.

My attempt:

I considered $f(x)=1+x^2$. Now if $f$ is Lipschitz, then $\exists L\in\mathbb{R}, \ \text{such that} \ \forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq L|x-y|.$$
Now, \begin{align}
L&\geq \frac{|1+x^2-1-y^2|}{|x-y|} \\
&=\frac{|(x-y)(x+y)|}{|x-y|} \\
&=|x+y|
\end{align}

I'm a bit unsure of how to proceed. How can I use the initial value conditions to further my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need for uniqueness is **local** Lipschitz property of $f(x)=1+x^2$: for any $x,y \in [a,b]$, by the Lagrange Theorem,
$$|f(x)-f(y)|=|f'(t)||x-y|\leq L|x-y|$$
where $L=\max\{2t : t\in [a,b]\}=2\max(|a|,|b|)$ (or, according to you approach, we can also take $L=2\max(|a|,|b|)\geq |x|+ |y|\geq |x+y|$).

By the way, in this case, uniqueness follows by solving the ODE after separating the variables:
$$\int_1^{x(t)}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\int_0^{t}dt\implies \arctan(x(t))-\frac{\pi}{4}=t\implies x(t)=\tan\left(t+\frac{\pi}{4}\right).$$

Comment: This helps a lot, thanks. For local Lipschitz, are there any restrictions on $a$ and $b$ in the interval $[a,b]$?

Comment: For instance, if I considered the interval $[0,2]$, then by the theorem $$L=\max_{x\in [0,2]}|f'(x)|=\max_{x\in [0,2]}|2x|=2(2)=4.$$ Does this show $f$ is local Lipschitz and hence a unique solution exists to the IVP?

Comment: @Bell No there are no restriction on $a$ and $b$. $f$ is local Lipschitz in $\mathbb{R}$. This means that a unique solution exists for any initial value. Note that this ODE is autonomous https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(mathematics)

Comment: So would my previous comment be correct? That is, is my example sufficient to show $f$ is local Lipschitz?

Comment: @Bell Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Hey @Robert Z I just have a quick question. If $f$ was some arbitrary function on a closed interval $[a,b]$, and $f$ was continuously differentiable, is this enough to say that $f$ is locally Lipschitz? Hence a unique solution to the IVP exists. This is related to my new post. I'd really appreciate your help, it is a bit stressful.